# Facebook comment box extending to my footer section

Tags: html, css, facebook

I added a facebook comment box to my [website](http://www.houseoftob.com) which allows 4 comments to show on the page but anytime I try to view additional comments it extends to my footer and not the main body of the page where it is placed. Can anyone help me to make the comment box automatically resize the page anytime a user wants to additional comments without it appearing in the footer.

Answer (score 0):

Set your `#contentBody` div height to auto, and add a div with `clear: both` just before you close your `.content` div.

Then you'll need to make your left vertical menu be the same height as the `#contentBody` in order for it to look good.
That way you'll be able to expand your comment list all day long and never break the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try add this css

```
.fbFeedbackContent {
    max-height: 500px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

**What I did:** First you need to set maximum height of content (F12 in your browser and inspect comment box to test max-height). Next you need to set overflow, that allows to define the property of the content *hided*.